# How can I write in MS Word with special positioning using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word

I have this code for opening and writing text on a Microsoft Word document.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;

        object oMissing = Type.Missing;
        oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;



        oWord.Documents.Open("f:\\test.docx");
        oWord.Selection.TypeText("Write your text here");
    }
```

My problem is, how can I write the text in the doc file with special formating(position, spacing, alignment, etc.)?

Comment: Usually you can use Range or Paragrapgh interfaces. Look at their's properties. Like Range.Font or Paragrapgh.TabIndent etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading this article. You can find basic text formatting as well as many other things may come handy:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx
4.3.3 describes text selection and 11.2 text formatting